# Add button on top of AVPlayerLayer - iOS Swift

Tags: button, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I'm trying to add a play button on top of my `AVPlayerLayer` but it's not showing up.

I have a `UIView` called `playerView` as an IBOutlet.

Here's how I create the `player` and a corresponding `playerLayer`, and put it in the `playerView`:

```
    player = AVPlayer()
    superLayer = self.playerView.layer
    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.playerView.bounds
    playerLayer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    superLayer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: playVideoButton)
```

The problem is that the `playVideoButton` doesn't show up on top of the the `playerLayer` (the button is added in the storyboard). I tried hiding the `playerLayer` and the button still doesn't show up underneath, so it seems the button's not even in the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

let btn = UIButton()
btn.frame = CGRect(x: 23, y: 34, width: 25, height: 30)

playerLayer.addSublayer(btn.layer)
self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
```